# HTMLAgilityPack missing child nodes that exist on website being scraped

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm running the following piece of code, it returns back the correct number of number of divs found for 'callTable'.. but they are all empty, the innerHTML is empty and it doesn't find any children for any of them, even though if you inspect the elements on the actual site, they have children.

I thought maybe it had to do with having a table within a div, so I tested it by looking within 'box-content' divs.  Those seem to be loading correctly though.  It is possible it has to do with the callTable has 'table-layout: fixed'?

Anyway, can't seem to find anyone else having this error after poking around.  Anyone have some thoughts?  Much appreciated!!

```
string Url = "https://malwr.com/analysis/MWI5MThhZWZhNDI0NDEyYThmOWMxMjc3MzRmZjQ1MDg"+id
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument webpage = web.Load(Url);

HtmlNodeCollection callTable = webpage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='calltable']");//[contains(@class, 'calltable')]");

//Just a test
HtmlNodeCollection boxContentTest = webpage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='box-content']");
```

Comment: Are the child elements generated via some sort of ajax or client side javascript?

Comment: That is exactly what is going on, much appreciated!  Now just have to figure out how to fix that... do you happen to know of a way to get around that?  Maybe I just have to go back to the approach of running these samples in Cuckoo Sandbox myself.. but that's kind of annoying for what I need.

Comment: There tons of questions about scraping JavaScript-generated content. Feel free to search... Browsing through questions in [web-scraping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) tag is one way to find the answer.